# Well-known text (wkt) validator

Tags: well-known-text, validation

Is there anything like http://jsonlint.com or http://geojsonlint.com for [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)? How can I validate a complex WKT string, say e.g. a Multipolygon?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/are-there-any-online-wkt-editors See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985484/php-validate-wkt-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible WKT validator can be PostGIS or a whatever spatial DBMS you like. For instance:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)');
```

is executed successfully, because `POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)` is a valid WKT representation. Instead:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.064544, 42.28787)');
```

returns:

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry HINT:  "POINT(-71.064544, "
>   <-- parse error at position 18 within geometry
>   ********* Error *********
>
> ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry SQL state: XX000 Hint:
>   "POINT(-71.064544, " <-- parse error at position 18 within geometry

because `POINT(-71.064544, 42.28787)` is not a valid WKT. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not as easy as an online copy'n'paste tool but if one already has a PostGIS installation, then it works :)