# Online WKT and GeoJSON viewer

Tags: geojson, well-known-text, validation, viewer

I once found a great but simple webpage that has a drop-down with several text-based GIS formats such as GeoJSON and WKT, and a text box to copy/paste your data. The feature is then drawn on a world map. You can continue to add shapes on the same map.

Does anyone know the page, or any page where I can paste WKT and GeoJSON to see them displayed on a map?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Look at [Are there any online WKT editors?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/are-there-any-online-wkt-editors)

GeoJSON and WKT

- [Geometrymapper: WKT & GeoJson Plotter](https://geometrymapper.com)
- [OpenLayers vector formats](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html)
- [WKT & GeoJSON Map Viewer](https://9revolution9.com/tools/geo/wkt_geojson/) (new)

GeoJSON

- [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0)
- [GeoJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/)
- [GeoJSON viewer](http://jansanchez.com/geojson-viewer/)
- and others

WKT

- [Wicket](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html)
- [OpenStreetMap WKT Playground](https://github.com/clydedacruz/openstreetmap-wkt-playground)

Comment: That first link for OpenLayers is the exact page I was looking for!!  Thanks so much - I'm not sure why I couldn't find it.

Comment: Love the OSM Playground!

Comment: Is it possible to specify the WKT as URL parameter, in order to share a shape with someone?

Answer (score 7):

I created this little utility for a co-worker to plot multiple WKT or GeoJSON geometries on a Leaflet map. You can fork it and tailor it to your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/asnyder14/9dxbcr4f/embedded/result/

Comment: Fantastic tool, thanks! (if'd be great it could accept more than WKT object at once... ;))

Comment: Exist a way for know when a point is inside `Polygon`

Comment: @jjmontes Easy enough: http://jsfiddle.net/eyal0/z4px7g30/12/

Answer (score 6):

wkt:
https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html
https://clydedacruz.github.io/openstreetmap-wkt-playground/
https://geometrymapper.com

geojson:
http://geojsonlint.com/

csv:
https://www.becsv.com/csv-viewer.php

.shapefile/geojson/csv:
https://mapshaper.org/
https://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/gps-view.php

svgviewer:
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_path

svg handling:
https://github.com/substack/svg-linearize
https://github.com/davidmcclure/svg-to-wkt
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle

geojson on leaflet:
[Adding GeoJSON layer on leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238303/adding-geojson-layer-on-leaflet/238385)

converters:
CSV to GeoJSON: http://csv.togeojson.com/
CSV to GeoJSON: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-geojson.htm
JSON to CSV: https://json-csv.com/
JSON to CSV: http://www.convertcsv.com/geojson-to-csv.htm
WKT to GeoJSON (printed in console): https://geometrymapper.com

examples:
wkt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#/media/File:SFA_Polygon.svg
csv: https://github.com/naturalatlas/geocsv-info/blob/master/example.csv
geojson: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/
svg path: https://jsbin.com/quhujowota/1/edit?html,js,output
svg path: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XogNoZ

Comment: ArcGIS JSON to GeoJSON: https://arcgisjson.togeojson.com/

Answer (score 2):

WKT visualizer on 3D Earth

https://asapelkin.github.io/wkt_3d_viewer

(repo with examples and readme https://github.com/asapelkin/wkt_3d_viewer)

Answer (score 2):

[GeoJSON Viewer (from URL)](https://gavinr.github.io/geojson-viewer/) gives a simple, quick map from a GeoJSON URL.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this question and needs to convert to/from Esri (ArcGIS) json, geoJson, or WKT, I created a small application called [geometry-inspector](https://github.com/BrianBunker/geometry-inspector). It is much like the listed applications in the accepted answer, but with the improvement that it supports Esri's json format.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Created a WKT <-> GeoJSON converter based on Wicket
http://jhnotes.com/wkt/

Answer (score 0):

[mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org/) worked well for huge GeoJson file but unfortunately it plots  on white background instead of map.

Answer (score 0):

For bash, I use my own script:  https://gist.github.com/rajanski/4d2595c1fd4e35c19b4e1a02b4ed579f
Pro: Geojson data doesnt leave local machine, good for confidential stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Github/Gists can handle GeoJSON:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/mapping-geojson-files-on-github

Answer (score 0):

For WKT there's also https://wktmap.com/ which supports different projections.

Answer (score 0):

WKT <-> GeoJSON converter and Map Viewer:
[WKT & GeoJSON Map Viewer](https://9revolution9.com/tools/geo/wkt_geojson/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Kepler.gl**
[https://kepler.gl/demo](https://%20https://kepler.gl/demo)

I can recommend the Kepler.gl demo where you can add your data in the following formats:

> CSV, Json, GeoJSON or saved map Json.

As data privacy is a concern when using online viewers, they state:

> *kepler.gl is a client-side application with no server backend. Data lives only on your machine/browser. No information or map data is sent
> to any server.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[geometrymapper](https://geometrymapper.com) is what you're looking for.
This Online Mapping Tool is capable of plotting WKT and GeoJson in different coordinate systems and colors. Really recommend it.
(mirror https://vannieuwenhovej.github.io/wkt-geometry-plotter)

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".