# Adding GeoJSON layer on leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, layers, html

i'm trying to load a geojson file on a leaflet map. here is the code :

body :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>map</title>
    <link href="leaflet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="loc_infra.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
var map = L.map('map',{
center:[5,28],
zoom: 3,
minZoom: 2,
maxZoom: 18,
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/ianmule.bg2v5cdi/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution: "Mapbox"}).addTo(map);

function basement (feature,layer){
layer.bindPopup("SURPRISE")
}

    var c2 = L.geoJson(loc_infra, {
            style:
            {
                weight: 4, 
                color: "red", 
                opacity: 1,
                fillColor: "red", 
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }, 
            onEachFeature: basement


        }).addTo(map);
```

and a little CSS :

```
html, body, #map {
height: 100%;
width:100%;
font-family:  : sans-serif;
}
```

and the geojson i'm trying to launch  :

```
var loc_infra = 
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [........
```

but my layer is not visible on the map, and i can't understand why !

Comment: Would you mind uploading this to https://jsfiddle.net  along with all your dependencies?

Comment: no problem : https://jsfiddle.net/NanBlanc/hxb3hoeu/#&togetherjs=navkRmVPeH PS: for the "loc_infra file, i upload it via "cjoint", because it's kind of huge file. here it is : http://www.cjoint.com/c/GDBhqkOuItG

Comment: @NanBlanc Please be careful with possible rude comments when you post publicly, even within your code…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the JavaScript code that you provide is within the `index.js` file?

In that case, you just have to re-order your `<script>` tags to make sure your `loc_infra` variable is defined and assigned *before* you try to use it:

```
<script src="loc_infra.js"></script> <!-- define and assign first -->
<script src="index.js"></script> <!-- now you can use it -->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/263/

When programming and debugging for the Web, make sure to use the browser console / [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (this describes for Chrome, but all browsers have something similar). In your case, it should report the error that `loc_infra` variable is `undefined`.

Later on, you can clean your architecture by actually loading a GeoJSON file (i.e. JSON format) instead of a JS file, typically using jQuery's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or through the [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) plugin.

Comment: THXXXX you're a genuis <3 this is it ! i didn't know that script calling order was so important ! 
and you guess it right, i'm a begginer who always forget about web console :)    

and by your last sentence, you mean that by calling the geojson directly in the js script with "getJSON", the script calling line in the html isn't needed anymore ?

Comment: Yes, and you also do not need to wrap your GeoJSON data with `var loc_infra = … ;`, so that it becomes really (Geo)JSON compliant.