# Is there any online viewer which displays the polygons assuming great circle lines for the edges?

Tags: spherical-geometry, geography, great-circle, online-viewer

My question is similar to this one: [Are there any online WKT editors?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/are-there-any-online-wkt-editors) The links given in answers have been very useful to me.

However, it seems that when the [tools](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html) in [question](http://orielo.com/projects/wkt2geojson) display maps, they assume the WKT describes a geometry and not a geography.

By this I mean that they assume the geometry is on a Cartesian coordinate system, and not a geographic coordinate system.

This causes the edges of the polygon to just connect the vertices with the shortest distance on the map, and not great circle distances on the map.

Is there any Viewer which displays the polygons assuming great circle lines for the edges, instead of assuming that edges are in Cartesian space?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by geographies ? [Well-known text (WKT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) is a text markup language for representing vector geometry objects on a map.

Comment: But PostGIS has a GeogFromText function, which accepts WKT input without trouble. This gives different results than GeomFromText does, for logical reasons. So how is WKT geometry-only?

Comment: But what you mean by geographies ? What is the difference with geometries for you ?

Comment: I think what you are trying to ask is: "Is there any Viewer which displays the polygons assuming Great Circle Lines for the edges, instead of assuming that Edges are in Cartesian Space" Is this correct?

Comment: Devdatta Tengshe, yes

Comment: look at [18. Geography](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html)

Comment: @ChrisMorrow: I have edited the question based on your comment. If this not what you were expecting, feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! This captures it correctly. (I just modified capitalization.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made an attempt at this using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/) and the [Arc.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/arcjs/) plugin:

http://snorf.net/wkt_gc/

Currently this works with `LINESTRING` and `POLYGON` strings. Just enter the WKT in the input box to the top right and it will update.

Comment: Any plans to bring this back online?

Comment: @dbaston I think this got wiped out accidentally when I changed blogging platform. I'll try and get it (or something similar) back up this week.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (in case you still need it)

https://asapelkin.github.io/wkt_3d_viewer

(repo with examples and readme https://github.com/asapelkin/wkt_3d_viewer)