# Visualize WKT polygon on a map

Tags: geometry, well-known-text

Is there any tool that will let me visualize a WKT polygon on a world map such as google maps?

Comment: Probably lots of tools. Are you looking for something web based, thick client based, or own-hosted based?

Comment: What GIS software are you already familiar with?  If you check the documentation and find that it appears not to do it when its product description suggests it should then that would make a more focussed Q&A than your currently quite broad question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/are-there-any-online-wkt-editors

Comment: I'm willing to look at free software but an online tool would be best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

**QGIS**: the QuickWKT plugin. The description of the tool is as follows:

> Quick WKT/WKB viewer, this Qgis Plugin opens a dialog where the user
>   can paste (E)WKT and WKB code and see it on the map. Pasted data are
>   stored in a temporay (memory) layer and are completely lost when the
>   user quits QGIS.

[image]

[**Wicket**](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html): if you need/want to do this in the browser.

Comment: WKT geometry can be read from a CSV file in QGIS, too. See Add Delimited Text Layer.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I can't wicket or other tools to work. Can you try with this and tell me what the problem is? `POLYGON((42.0095169 -124.415165, 42.0095169 -119.2732788, 37.2718906 -119.2732788, 37.2718906 -124.415165, 42.0095169 -124.415165))`

Comment: Reverse your latitude and longitude.

Comment: Really? So you're saying WKT is always lng, lat instead of lat, lng? That seems very strange to me, I don't understand why that would be a thing.

Comment: It's always `(x, y)`, it doesn't know anything about longitude or latitude.

Comment: Ok so for geo coordinates WKT is always lng, lat. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: No, it's always `(x, y)`. That is equivalent to `(lon, lat)`, but does not have to be: they could be projected coordinates.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but can you please explain what you mean by projected coordinates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34471/discussion-between-richard-law-and-pguardiario).

Comment: Sorry, I had to go to bed. Basically I'm asking if with Google maps or Wicket, it's always lng, lat or am I still missing something?

Comment: I don't know how I can make this any clearer. With WKT, the order is `(x, y)`, or `(easting, northing)`. Think of a graph with x and y axes: vertical and horizontal. When using latitude and longitude coordinates, the x dimension is longitude, and the y dimension is latitude, so therefore WKT needs your location given as `(lng, lat)`. Is that clear?

Comment: Sure. A simple yes would have been clearer :)

Comment: Some reading @pguardiario: http://www.macwright.org/lonlat/