# Pretty-printing WKT strings?

Tags: well-known-text, tools, formatting

Is there a tool that will pretty-print well-known-text strings? One that would accept for instance

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), ((20 35, 45 20, 30 5, 20 35)))
```

and output something like

```
MULTIPOLYGON (
  (
    (
      40 40,
      20 45,
      45 30,
      40 40
    ),
  ),
  (
    (
      20 35,
      45 20,
      30  5,
      20 35
    )
  )
```

Ideally this would be an online tool that runs in a browser (along the lines of the [many JSON formatters](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+json+formatter) that exist), but an offline tool would still be useful.

There are a number of [online tools for viewing and editing WKT-format data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/seeking-online-wkt-editor), but none that seem to offer any support for reformatting. [The OpenLayers vector-formats example app](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html) has a checkbox tantalizingly labelled "Pretty print", but selecting it seems not to do anything when WKT is set as the output format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenJUMP http://openjump.org can do that on desktop.

Compressed format that is good for copy-paste

[image]

Beautified format that helps visual interpretation

[image]